# how to halt the execution until a method returns a value in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am almost a newbie in `java threading`. I have a scenario whereby I am posting `JSON` messages in a `rabbitmq queue` and an external service is performing operation on the `JSON` received and then after the execution of the external service, it will return a value in `integer` indicating whether the execution went successful or not.

I want to call the external service and then want to wait for the return value i.e make the execution of the producer halt until consumer function returns me the value.

Your help is highly appreciable. Just give me the topic like whether to use synchronized methods, or Future and Callable interfaces etc.

Thanks. Please don't say that "show us what you have tried till now etc", I just need your suggestions about how to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a classic producer-consumer problem I tried some time ago... do not have the link to the original blog/tutorial, but here's the code instead:

```
 public class ProducerConsumerTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CubbyHole c = new CubbyHole();
    Producer p1 = new Producer(c, 1);
    Consumer c1 = new Consumer(c, 1);
    p1.start(); 
    c1.start();
  }
}
class CubbyHole {
 private int contents;
 private boolean available = false;
 public synchronized int get() {
   while (available == false) {
      try {
        wait();
       }
       catch (InterruptedException e) {
       }
    }
    available = false;
    notifyAll();
    return contents;
 }
  public synchronized void put(int value) {
    while (available == true) {
     try {
        wait();
     }
     catch (InterruptedException e) { 
     } 
    }
    contents = value;
    available = true;
    notifyAll();
 }
}

class Consumer extends Thread {
   private CubbyHole cubbyhole;
   private int number;
   public Consumer(CubbyHole c, int number) {
    cubbyhole = c;
   this.number = number;
   }
  public void run() {
     int value = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        value = cubbyhole.get();
          System.out.println("Consumer #" + this.number+ " got: " + value);
   }
  }
  }

  class Producer extends Thread {
  private CubbyHole cubbyhole;
  private int number;

 public Producer(CubbyHole c, int number) {
 cubbyhole = c;
 this.number = number;
 }

 public void run() {
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   cubbyhole.put(i);
   System.out.println("Producer #" + this.number+ " put: " + i);
    try {
    sleep((int)(Math.random() * 100));
     } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
  }
 }
 }
```

The trick is to put the producer thread to sleep till the consumer finishes consuming the previous elements. In the sample code I provided, sleep does the trick

...same effect can be achieved through a good old while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `join()` function is very common both in name and function in many programming languages, including Java. What it does is simply to let the calling thread wait until callee/child thread is done, ei. it waits until the child thread has returned.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("1");
        // Something that takes a long time to compute.
    }
 };
 t.start();
 t.join();
 System.out.println("2");
```

The output will be in order. As the last line will not be reached until t is finished and has returned.